# vbscript to check in excel file

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vbscript

I'm trying to write a vbscript to be able to checkout an excel file that is stored on sharepoint server.

Currently I can check the file out from [SharePoint 2010: Link to open Excel file in edit-mode mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000110/sharepoint-2010-link-to-open-excel-file-in-edit-mode-mode)

However, I'm trying to check the file back in but not able to.  I've searched and tried the checkout functions per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194456%28v=office.14%29.aspx but not able to.

Currently the code I have is

```
Sub CheckInFile

    Dim ExcelApp, ExcelSheet, ExcelBook
    Dim myURL

    myURL = "http://server/Site/excel.xlsx"

    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")                        

    If (ExcelApp.WorkBooks.CanCheckIn(myURL) = True) Then
        msgbox ("here")
        ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Open (myURL)
        ExcelApp.Application.WorkBooks.CheckIn myURL

        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ' Quit Excel.
        ExcelApp.Quit
        ' Clean Up
        Set ExcelApp= Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

However the script stops and fails at the if statement, rather doesn't execute.  Is there a similar vbscript function to check in a file ?

Comment: Stops and fails? Whats the exception you're getting?

Comment: Hi there, no exception ... its done on a website on sharepoint server ... the whole script just stops and never gets to the message box prompt for debugging
I know its the if statement because if i comment it out, i can get to message box but the other problem i'd face would be 

"ExcelApp.Application.WorkBooks.CheckIn myURL"

Comment: Hi Ryan,

Upon running the IE script debugger, the error i'm getting is "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'ExcelApp.WorkBooks.CanCheckIn' "

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a LOT with this and spent many hours searching for a solution that worked in my particular environment. Here are my criteria that needed to be met:

- Execute the process from my computer using vbscript file
- Iterate through a list of ~200 excel spreadsheets
- Check out each file
- Make various conditional updates and save
- Check the file back in again when updates are complete.

Below is an alternate solution for anybody in the future that, like me, tried the suggested approach and it didn't work. This is tested and working:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim MyVar ' so popup alerts narrate the process
          ' and help explain what is happening
          ' for those who want to see it step
          ' by step
Dim docPath
docPath = "\\your server\sites\Docs\sharepoint spreadsheet.xlsx"
' I believe this can be any document path

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(docPath)

cco = objExcel.Workbooks.CanCheckOut(docPath)

MyVar = MsgBox ("can check out? " & cco, 0) 
' -----------------------------------------------------
' this shows "False" every time. I still do not know how 
' to get this to work, but thought it would be valuable
' to include for explanation
' -----------------------------------------------------

objExcel.Workbooks.CheckOut(docPath)
' -----------------------------------------------------
' this SUCCEEDS every time...as long as you have
' the ability to check out the document manually
' -----------------------------------------------------

MyVar = MsgBox ("Update cell", 0)
With objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    objExcel.Cells( 1, 1 ).Value = "test value"
End With

MyVar = MsgBox ("Save the file", 0)
objWorkbook.Save

MyVar = MsgBox ("check in the file", 0)

objWorkbook.CheckIn
' -----------------------------------------------------
' This actually checks in the active document and *closes 
' it* You don't have to have a separate command to close
' the file, e.g.
'   objWorkbook.Close 
' THIS WILL FAIL.
' -----------------------------------------------------

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

Comment: Looked for awhile to solve my issue (which was also your issue) and stumbled across this. Thank you for posting. It has helped me out tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
Dim ExcelApp, ExcelSheet, ExcelBook
    Dim myURL = "http://server/Site/excel.xlsx"
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")                        
    ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Open (myURL)
    If (ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.CanCheckIn = True) Then
        ExcelApp.Application.WorkBooks(myURL).CheckIn 
        ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        ' Quit Excel.
        ExcelApp.Quit
        ' Clean Up
        Set ExcelApp= Nothing
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change include below lines to your code:

```
ExcelApp.Visible = True
ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Thanks!

```
 Dim oExcel
 Dim strFileName
 Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 oExcel.Visible = True
 oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
 strFileName = "view_2019.xlsm"

'Checkin
 If oExcel.Workbooks(strFileName).CanCheckIn = True Then
   oExcel.Workbooks(strFileName).CheckIn SaveChanges=True,Comments="Updated"
   MsgBox strFileName  & " has been checked in."
 Else
   MsgBox "This file cannot be checked in at this time. Please try again later."
 End If
 set oExcel = nothing
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer?